# Coordinating Controller design pattern in Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, design-patterns, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm creating an iOS application with lots of custom views, so, using default Cocoa views was not an option. Then, I decided to go with the **Coordinating / Mediator Controller** design patter (learned in Apress - Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS).

From the delegate, I create a rootViewController pointing to the view in my coordinating controller:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
coordinatingController = [C6CoordinatingController sharedInstance];
self.window.rootViewController = coordinatingController.activeVC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Then, in the coordinating controller, I have singleton creation methods:

```
+ (C6CoordinatingController *) sharedInstance{
if (sharedCoordinator == nil){
    C6Log(@"New Shared Coordinator");
    sharedCoordinator = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    [sharedCoordinator initialize];
}
else {
    C6Log(@"Return Singleton Shared Coordinator");
}
return sharedCoordinator;
}



+ (id) allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
return [self sharedInstance];
}



- (void) initialize{
C6Log(@"");
[self checkDevice];

_mainVC = [C6MainViewController initWithDevice:device];
_activeVC = _mainVC;
[self checkLanguage];
[self chooseFirstView];
}
```

I also have a selector to choose the first view (I only have two at this time):

```
-(void) chooseFirstView{
// If a language was not setted, go to language settings view
if (!language) {
    C6Log(@"Going to Language Settings");
    C6LanguageSettingsViewController *languageVC = [C6LanguageSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
    [_mainVC.view addSubview:languageVC.view];
}
else {
    C6Log(@"Going to User Settings", language);
    C6AccountSettingsViewController *accountVC = [C6AccountSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
    [_mainVC.view addSubview:accountVC.view];
}
}
```

Then, I have an IBAction to be used by my views:

```
- (IBAction) requestViewChangeByObject:(id)object {
int buttonTag = [object tag]; // dividend
int viewTag = buttonTag / divisor; // quotient
int actionTag = buttonTag - (divisor * viewTag); // remainder
C6Log(@"viewTag: %d | actionTag %d", viewTag, actionTag);
switch (viewTag) {
    case LanguageTags:
        C6Log(@"LanguageTags");
        break;
    case AccountTags:
        C6Log(@"AccountTags");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

In the NIB, I created an Obect (Coordinating Controller) an I call the IBAction from there. It works just fine and I can change my views (it still needs to be implemented)………

BUT… I also want to change the language, but, as it is not a navigation issue, I wanto to do it from the C6LanguageSettingsViewController and not from the C6CoodinatingController.

So, I created another IBAction in the C6LanguageSettingsViewController:

```
- (IBAction)chooseLang:(id)sender{
UIImage *bt;
[self resetImagesToNormalState];
C6Log(@""); 
C6Log(@"%@", [sender tag]);
C6Log(@"%@", sender);
.
.
.
```

When I connect the button to this IBAction (through File's Owner OR via an LanguageSettingsViewController object), the app breakes and, sometime it shows no error and, sometimes it presents **Unrecognized selector sent to instance** OR **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code=1, address = 0x………)** in the UIApplicationMain.

I believe the problem is the NIB doesn't find the file's owner… but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok… it seems absurd, but I'm answering myself :P

I managed to make it work (finaly!) and I found I was managing the viewControllers in a BAAAAD way, so, I changed some code in the coordinating controller:

First, I don't have a "real" mainViewController with NIBs and stuf no more…

**OLD initialize**

```
- (void) initialize{
    C6Log(@"");
    [self checkDevice];
    _mainVC = [C6MainViewController initWithDevice:device];
    _activeVC = _mainVC;
    [self checkLanguage];
    [self chooseFirstView];
}
```

**NEW initialize**

```
- (void) initialize{
    C6Log(@"");
    [self checkDevice];
    [self checkLanguage];
    [self chooseFirstView];
}
```

*checkDevice* verifies if it's iPhone or iPad, so I can choose the right NIB.

*checkLanguage* checks the [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] for the language

Finaly, I call chooseFirstView:

**OLD chooseFirstView**

```
-(void) chooseFirstView{
    // If a language was not setted, go to language settings view
    if (!language) {
        C6Log(@"Going to Language Settings");
        C6LanguageSettingsViewController *languageVC = [C6LanguageSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
        [_mainVC.view addSubview:languageVC.view];
    }
    else {
        C6Log(@"Going to User Settings", language);
        C6AccountSettingsViewController *accountVC = [C6AccountSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
        [_mainVC.view addSubview:accountVC.view];
    }
}
```

**NEW chooseFirstView**

```
-(void) chooseFirstView{
    // If a language was not setted, go to language settings view
    _activeVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
    [_activeVC.view addSubview:bgView];

    if (!language) {
        C6Log(@"Going to Language Settings");
        languageVC = [C6LanguageSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
        [_activeVC.view addSubview:languageVC.view];
    }
    else {
        C6Log(@"Going to User Settings", language);
        accountVC = [C6AccountSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
        [_activeVC.view addSubview:accountVC.view];
    }
}
```

The big change is WHEN and HOW I initiated the _activeVC… AND the fact that both _languageVC and _accountVC are now global variables.

Well, after this changes, the NIB button call both IBAction methods: it's file's owner and the coordinating controller.

Another BIG thing about using this kind of pattern is how to change from one view to another without explode iOS device memory… here's how I do it inside the coordinating controller:

```
- (IBAction) requestViewChangeByObject:(id)object {
    int buttonTag = [object tag]; // dividend
    int viewTag = buttonTag / divisor; // quotient
    int actionTag = buttonTag - (divisor * viewTag); // remainder
    C6Log(@"ViewTag: %d", viewTag);
    switch (viewTag) {
        case LanguageTags:{
            C6Log(@"LanguageTags - button %d", actionTag);
            accountVC = [C6AccountSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
            UIView *fromView = languageVC.view;
            UIView *toView = accountVC.view;
            [self switchFrom:fromView To:toView usingAnimation:AnimationPushFromRigh];
        }
            break;
        case AccountTags:{
            C6Log(@"AccountTags - button %d", actionTag);
            switch (actionTag) {
                case 0:{
                    C6Log(@"Go back");
                    languageVC = [C6LanguageSettingsViewController initWithDevice:device];
                    UIView *fromView = accountVC.view;
                    UIView *toView = languageVC.view;
                    [self switchFrom:fromView To:toView usingAnimation:AnimationPushFromLeft];
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

In the beginning of the method, I do a lot of math… I "created" a pattern where each NIB should have it's tags beginning with 100 multiples… so, language begins with 0, account with 100………

```
#define divisor         100
#define LanguageTags    0
#define AccountTags     1
```

Then, the way I change from one view to another is right there:

```
-(void) switchFrom:(UIView*) fromView To:(UIView*) toView usingAnimation:(int) animation{
    C6Log(@"");
    /*************** SET ALL DEFAULT TRANSITION SETTINGS ***************/
    // Get the current view frame, width and height
    CGRect pageFrame = fromView.frame;
    CGFloat pageWidth = pageFrame.size.width;
    // Create the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    // Create the delegate, so the "fromView" is removed after the transition
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate: fromView];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    // Set the transition duration
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.4];

    // Add the "toView" as subview of "fromView" superview
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

    switch (animation) {
        case AnimationPushFromRigh:{
            // Position the "toView" to the right corner of the page            
            toView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, pageWidth,0);
            // Animate the "fromView" to the left corner of the page
            fromView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, -pageWidth,0);
            // Animate the "toView" to the center of the page
            toView.frame = pageFrame;
            // Animate the "fromView" alpha
            fromView.alpha = 0;
            // Set and animate the "toView" alpha
            toView.alpha = 0;
            toView.alpha = 1;

            // Commit the animation
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
            break;
        case AnimationPushFromLeft:{
            // Position the "toView" to the left corner of the page         
            toView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, -pageWidth,0);
            // Animate the "fromView" to the right corner of the page
            fromView.frame = CGRectOffset(pageFrame, pageWidth,0);
            // Animate the "toView" to the center of the page
            toView.frame = pageFrame;
            // Animate the "fromView" alpha
            fromView.alpha = 0;
            // Set and animate the "toView" alpha
            toView.alpha = 0;
            toView.alpha = 1;

            // Commit the animation
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I really hope this helps who's trying to use this coordinating controller pattern :P